# spring security url regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using regular expression to restrict sections of my website and sometimes subsections as well, but there is kind of url which I am not able to restrict so far, and that is with parameters.

```
<intercept-url pattern="^/(?i)(hardcopy|hardcopy/[^/]*|china_digest)/(article)?(\d+)(\.|/).*$"
 access="isPanicking() or check14DayAccess() or checkFeatureIndicator() or (isAuthenticated() and hasGotPermission('title:UP', 'product:UP,ONUP,UPON') and getAccessDetails())"/>
```

Now as you could see hardcopy subsections are restricted when I use `hardcopy/[^/]*` but I have two url's `www.website.com/china_digest/?hashedzmagsid=dd4da72e&magsid=248106` and `www.website.com/china_digest/2004/article1189217.ece`, this I am not able to block with the same pattern. Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What URL do you want to block? the regex indeed says that `www.website.com/china_digest/` shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @Robin yes, I want to block this url `china_digest/?hashedzmagsid=dd4da72e&magsid=248106`.

Comment: @Joe I have a different pattern altogether. And have tried as suggested in that. I tried something like this `china_digest/[^/\?]*` but it didnt work.